# Use code completion with imported classes in VS Code

Tags: javascript, import, export, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I'm currently developing a web-application for managing one's inventory in [D&D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons). Now, as I'm writing classes for the different items, I've noticed that Visual Studio Code doesn't auto-complete the imported class as desired.

Example:

```
class Weapon {
  constructor(damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }
  setDamage(damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }
}

// typing "var sword = new Weapon(" here will offer code completion
```

Now if I import this (using Webpack), it does *not* work:

```
import Weapon from "path/to/weapon.js";

// typing "var weapon = new Weapon(" will *not* offer any suggestions


// weapon.js looks like this:
export default class Weapon {
  constructor(damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }
  setDamage(damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what the problem is? Am I importing/exporting my class wrong? Or do I simply need an additional plugin to gain this functionality in VS Code?

Comment: Works fine for me : import Weapon from "./subfolder/weapon";  where weapon.js is in the subfolder directory.  Does your path have the "./"  ?  It makes a difference.

Comment: my path has a "../path/weapon.js". The path is definitely correct, though - if I create a "var armor = new Armor()" and log it to the console, it shows the desired class with undefined fields. I'm just not getting code completion in VS Code (possibly not in other editors? I'll try that tomorrow to see if the problem really is with VS Code)

Comment: Try without the .js too.

Comment: Found the problem - I used `@/assets/etc` as my path; `@` is the project root, but VS Code doesn't know that during code writing, it's defined by webpack during build. Anybody know how to tell VS Code what `@` means?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14907  There are people dealing with your precise issue.